# DynamoDB backup to s3 using DataPipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to setup a pipline for backuping DynamoDB 
I almost got it ... 
I have no default VPC and I can't change that

The backup task is not able to locate the region I'm using 
In syslog I receive the following error:

> 2016-04-11 08:53:32,444 WARN org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBUtil
>   (main): Exception when attempting to get AWS region information. Will
>   ignore and default to us-east-1

And this leads to in stderr:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not
>   lookup Table dev_user in DynamoDB.

Parts of my pipeline definitions:

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "output": {
        "ref": "S3BackupLocation"
      },
      "input": {
        "ref": "DDBSourceTable"
      },
      "maximumRetries": "2",
      "name": "TableBackupActivity",
      "step": "s3://dynamodb-emr-#{myDDBRegion}/emr-ddb-storage-handler/2.1.0/emr-ddb-2.1.0.jar,org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.tools.DynamoDbExport,#{output.directoryPath},#{input.tableName},#{input.readThroughputPercent}",
      "id": "TableBackupActivity",
      "runsOn": {
        "ref": "EmrClusterForBackup"
      },
      "type": "EmrActivity",
      "resizeClusterBeforeRunning": "true"
    },
...
    {
...
      "coreInstanceCount": "1",
      "releaseLabel": "emr-4.5.0",
      "masterInstanceType": "m3.xlarge",
      "type": "EmrCluster",
      "terminateAfter": "1 Hour",
      "name": "EmrClusterForBackup",
      "coreInstanceType": "m3.xlarge",
      "id": "EmrClusterForBackup",
      "region": "eu-west-1"
    },
    {
      "readThroughputPercent": "#{myDDBReadThroughputRatio}",
      "name": "DDBSourceTable",
      "id": "DDBSourceTable",
      "type": "DynamoDBDataNode",
      "region": "eu-west-1",
      "tableName": "dev_user"
    }
  ],
  "parameters": [
...
    {
      "default": "eu-west-1",
      "watermark": "eu-west-1",
      "description": "Region of the DynamoDB table",
      "id": "myDDBRegion",
      "type": "String"
    }
  ],
  "values": {
    "myDDBRegion": "eu-west-1",
    "myDDBTableName": "dev_user",
    "myDDBReadThroughputRatio": "0.25",
...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I get your pipeline ID?

Also could you specify the resizeClusterBeforeRunning to be "false" and try it again.

Thanks

Comment: ID = df-1032751PQF9X1MM1G3X

Why resize would change anything? 
Anyway tried it and didn't work. Still unable to set the proper region for EmrActivity

Comment: I am not sure what will cause this problem. Could you try with older version of release label cluster, or use data pipeline template to export DDB to s3, which use AMI version cluster.  I have tried with data pipeline template, it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in AWS and there is no possible way to make it work in a private subnet. 
To use a pipeline for dynamodb backup you have to set it up in a public subnet.